# How can I link a step wizard to a menu using a next button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a vertical menu with submenu's, my menu works as a step by step form.
Everytime I click on the next button the wizard must go to the next step  and must also go to the next menu list. My menu list also have a href for the pages of the form.

for example: step 1 is menu called trucks,the truck page opens
             step 2 is menu called dates, dates page opens

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Initialize tooltips
  //$('.nav-tabs > li a[title]').tooltip();

  //Wizard
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {

    var $target = $(e.target);

    if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
      return false;
    }
  });

  $(".next").click(function(e) {

    var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
    $active.next().removeClass('disabled');
    nextTab($active);

  });

});

function nextTab(elem) {
  $(elem).next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
}
```

```css
/* MENU */

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .menu {
    width: 72.5%;
    left: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #129cf3;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    font: 18px 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    top: 250px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-bottom: none;
    transition: all 1s;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
  }
  .menu li {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

.menu a {
  color: #000;
  left: 800px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 35px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #129cf3;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #129cf3;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu i {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.menu-list li a {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* WIZARD CONTAINER  */

.container {
  width: 80%;
}


/*NEXT BUTTON  */

.action-button {
  width: 80px;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  position: relative;
  left: 190px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #129cfe;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.action-button:hover {
  background-color: #129cf3;
  border: 1px solid #129cfe;
  color: #000;
}


/* WIZARD*/

.wizard {
  margin: 5px auto;
  background: #fff;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.wizard>div.wizard-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.connecting-line {
  height: 2px;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 63%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.wizard .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover,
.wizard .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
  color: #129cf3;
  cursor: default;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

span.round-tab {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #e0e0e0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  top: 35%;
}

span.round-tab i {
  color: #129cf3;
}

.wizard li.active span.round-tab {
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #129cf3;
}

.wizard li.active span.round-tab i {
  color: #129cf3;
}

span.round-tab:hover {
  color: #333;
  border: 2px solid #333;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs>li {
  width: 25%;
}

.wizard li:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 46%;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #129cfe;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.wizard li.active:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 47.55%;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #129cf3;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs>li a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 35px auto;
  border-radius: 0%;
  padding: 0;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs>li a:hover {
  background: transparent;
}

.wizard .tab-pane {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.wizard h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.step1 .row {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.step_21 {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.step33 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.dropselectsec {
  width: 68%;
  padding: 6px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #333;
  margin-left: 10px;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.dropselectsec1 {
  width: 74%;
  padding: 6px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #333;
  margin-left: 10px;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.mar_ned {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wdth {
  width: 25%;
}

.birthdrop {
  padding: 6px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #333;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 16%;
  outline: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

@media( max-width: 585px) {
  .wizard {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto !important;
  }
  span.round-tab {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
  span.round-tab i {
    color: #555555;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  .wizard .nav-tabs>li a {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
  .wizard li.active:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="trucks.html" target="preview-iframe">Book Trucks</a></li>
      <li class="active"> <a href="schedule.html" target="preview-iframe" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggle1" class="collapsed">Schedule <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="toggle1">
          <ul class="menu-list">
            <li><a href="start.html" target="preview-iframe"> Start Date</a></li>
            <li><a href="end.html" target="preview-iframe"> End Date</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="active"> <a href="routes.html" target="preview-iframe" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggle" class="collapsed">Routes <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="toggle">
          <ul class="menu-list">
            <li><a href="routes2.html" target="preview-iframe">Route 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="routes3.html" target="preview-iframe">Route 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="routes4.html" target="preview-iframe">Route 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="routes5.html" target="preview-iframe">Route 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="region.html" target="preview-iframe">Availability Regions</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section>
        <div class="wizard">
          <div class="wizard-inner">
            <div class="connecting-line"></div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
              <li role="presentation" class="active" id="step1">
                <a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Step 1"> <span class="round-tab">
                                    <i class="fa fa-truck"></i>
                                </span> </a>
              </li>
              <li role="presentation" class="disabled" id="step2">
                <a href="#step4" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Step 2"> <span class="round-tab">
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                </span> </a>
              </li>
              <li role="presentation" class="disabled" id="step3">
                <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Step 3"> <span class="round-tab">
                                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                                </span> </a>
              </li>
              <li role="presentation" class="disabled" id="complete">
                <a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="complete" role="tab" title="Step 4"> <span class="round-tab">
                                    <i class="fa fa-table"></i>
                                </span> </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" onclick="next" /> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".next").click(function(e) {
  var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
  $active.removeClass('active');

  var $next = $active.next();
  $next.removeClass('disabled');
  $next.children('a').click();
  // or
  // $next.first().click();
});
```

**Edited:**
Added `iframe`'s `src` manipulation.

```
$(".next").click(function(e) {
  var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
  $active.removeClass('active');

  var $next = $active.next();
  $next.removeClass('disabled');

  var $link = $next.children('a');
  $link.click();

  var $iframe = $('#iframe');
  $iframe.attr('src', $link.attr('href'));
});
```

**Edited:**
Added user behavior

```
$(".next").click(function(e) {
  var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
  var $link;

  if ($active.length === 0) {
    $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li').first();
    $active.addClass('active');

    $link = $active.children('a');
  } else {
    $active.removeClass('active');
    var $next = $active.next();
    $next.removeClass('disabled');

    $link = $next.children('a');
  }

  $link.click();

  var $iframe = $('#iframe');
  $iframe.attr('src', $link.attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: How can I connect my menu href to the wizard, so if people click on next it will open a page in the iframe? The wizard and menu must connect with the next button, so if people start at trucks, the next button should take the user to the next page on the menu and shift the wizard to the 2nd icon

Comment: You can manipulate with `iframe` using it's `src` attribute. Insert there your `href` value.

Comment: A little explanation would be nice.

Comment: @SinDeus you can look to the answer, I added this behavior there.

Comment: Thank you Mike for your help, much appreciated.  http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/ZlMjM I want my menu to do this, and also move the step wizard to the side, but instead of the content/paragraphs, I want it to open multiple pages/href

Comment: @MixiRocking do you mean multiple iframes?

Comment: its one iframe, i target the href to the iframe like this:  <li><a href="trucks.html" target="preview-iframe">Book Trucks</a></li>

Comment: sorry its not multiple links, only different links

Comment: I'm going to try and explain better, I want to connect/link my step wizard/progressbar with my nav menu, so if someone click on the next button,then the first page of my nav menu will open

Comment: so you want to open menu at the left side when someone clicks on the next button, right? and the first list become active and the first page available in the iframe, correct?